# How to properly connect to sql server in python using pypyodb

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pypyodbc

When I type in the code:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=ServerName, database=DatabaseName, uid=UserId, pwd=Password)
```

I get this error:

> ProgrammingError: (u'42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'master..sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.")

Does anyone know how to fix it?