# 'master..sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect my flask application with Azure database and that is when I encounter this error. I can't find anything on it, any help would be appreciated.

```
pypyodbc.connect(
    Driver={SQL Server};Server=tcp:******.net,1433;Database=***;UID=***;PWD=***;
)
```

Comment: Simple...don't use deprecated views. use sys.databases. this of course has been asked and answered plenty of times.

Comment: @SeanLange Is it OP trying to do this or the `pypyodbc` library though?

Comment: @SeanLange, please reopen this question as the duplicate question does not address what I am asking. I am using `pyodbc` library as specified by DavidG.

Comment: @DavidG that could be I suppose. I sure read this as trying to use the view. I think what you are suggesting is that perhaps the pypyodbc library is trying to view the deprecated view? If that is the case maybe it needs to be updated.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, looks like it does it on connect, nasty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201916/how-to-properly-connect-to-sql-server-in-python-using-pypyodb

Comment: Yuck...that sounds like a major issue with that library. That view has been deprecated for close to 15 years now. Surely there is an update by now?

Comment: A library shouldn't even try to query the database list on connect anyway!

Comment: Is there any workarounds?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pypyodbc (1.3.5.2)? And what version of SQL Server are you connecting to?

Comment: I am using `pyodbc version 1.3.4`, and I couldn't update to `1.3.5.2`. Also, `sql server 13`

Comment: What does "couldn't update" mean?

Comment: I have tried `pip install pypyodbc==1.3.5.2`, and it installs `1.3.4` instead. That's why I couldn't update it.

Comment: I looked for the text `sysdatabases` in the latest version on Github and couldn't find the text. Sadly I don't see a tag for version 1.3.4 for pypyodbc, so if that version uses that deprecated view and you can't upgrade your version, I think you're SOL.

Comment: I can upgrade it, but I couldn't when I tried. `pip install pypyodbc==1.3.5.2` is installing `1.3.4`. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @HafizTemuri - The version numbers you cited show that you are indeed using `pypyodbc`. You could try using `pyodbc` instead of `pypyodbc` and see if that helps any. (The current version of `pyodbc` is `4.0.22`.)

Comment: `sysdatabases` does exist in Azure. You should  post the **full** error message which presumably is `Reference to database and/or server name in 'master..sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.` that three part naming is not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by your combination of

1. pypyodbc
2. the ancient ODBC driver named "SQL Server", and
3. Azure SQL

When pypyodbc tries to establish the connection via `pypyodbc.connect` one of the (many!) things it does is try to determine whether you have read-only or read-write access to the database. The ODBC call that it uses is translated by the "SQL Server" ODBC driver as

```sql
select substring('NY',status/1024&1+1,1) from master..sysdatabases where name=DB_NAME()
```

which Azure SQL apparently does not like.

By comparison, a more modern ODBC driver like "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" translates that same ODBC call into

```sql
SELECT CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX( DB_NAME(), 'Updateability') WHEN 'READ_ONLY' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

which may be more palatable to Azure SQL.

So, you can either switch to a newer ODBC driver, or you can try using pyodbc instead of pypyodbc since pyodbc does not seem to query the RO/RW status of the database when it connects.

Comment: "pyodbc instead of pypyodbc".. this helped me. Thanks.